ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED error in Node postcss project in Maven Build
I am trying to run a maven build of an open source project and am getting the error in a Node subproject : ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED
The project is https://github.com/wso2-incubator/scim2-compliance-test-suite/tree/test-suite-v2 and it is this branch and not the master.  They are very different.
The error I get is
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:exec (npm run build (compile)) @ org.wso2.scim2.testsuite.endpoint ---

> webapp@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:617
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/ks891232/compliancev2/scim2-compliance-test-suite/components/org.wso2.scim2.testsuite.endpoint/src/main/webapp/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/postcss/package.json
    at exportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:303:10)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:650:9)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:610:36)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:700:31)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1188:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1027:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1290:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:188:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ks891232/compliancev2/scim2-compliance-test-suite/components/org.wso2.scim2.testsuite.endpoint/src/main/webapp/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/lib/safe-parser.js:1:17)
    
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1455:14) {
    
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED
}

I do not use Node so please excuse any mistakes I make describing this.
The message tell me that './lib/tokenize'is not listed in package.json.  But package.json is generated by the maven job so I can’t control it.
How do I correct the package.json?
Since it already been created by the maven job, can I manually change it and have the maven job use my updated one?
The generated package.json is:
{
  "name": "postcss",
  "version": "8.2.6",
  "description": "Tool for transforming styles with JS plugins",
  "engines": {
    "node": "^10 || ^12 || >=14"
  },
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "require": "./lib/postcss.js",
      "import": "./lib/postcss.mjs",
      "types": "./lib/postcss.d.ts"
    },
    "./": "./"
  },
  "main": "./lib/postcss.js",
  "types": "./lib/postcss.d.ts",
  "keywords": [
    "css",
    "postcss",
    "rework",
    "preprocessor",
    "parser",
    "source map",
    "transform",
    "manipulation",
    "transpiler"
  ],
  "funding": {
    "type": "opencollective",
    "url": "https://opencollective.com/postcss/"
  },
  "author": "Andrey Sitnik <andrey@sitnik.ru>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "https://postcss.org/",
  "repository": "postcss/postcss",
  "dependencies": {
    "colorette": "^1.2.1",
    "nanoid": "^3.1.20",
    "source-map": "^0.6.1"
  },
  "browser": {
    "./lib/terminal-highlight": false,
    "colorette": false,
    "fs": false
  }
}

The contents of components/org.wso2.scim2.testsuite.endpoint/src/main/webapp/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/postcss/lib/ are:
at-rule.d.ts
    at-rule.js
    comment.d.ts
    comment.js
    container.d.ts
    container.js
    css-syntax-error.d.ts
    css-syntax-error.js
    declaration.d.ts
    declaration.js
    fromJSON.d.ts
    fromJSON.js
    input.d.ts
    input.js
    lazy-result.d.ts
    lazy-result.js
    list.d.ts
    list.js
    map-generator.js
    node.d.ts
    node.js
    parse.d.ts
    parse.js
    parser.js
    postcss.d.ts
    postcss.js
    postcss.mjs
    previous-map.d.ts
    previous-map.js
    processor.d.ts
    processor.js
    result.d.ts
    result.js
    root.d.ts
    root.js
    rule.d.ts
    rule.js
    stringifier.js
    stringify.d.ts
    stringify.js
    symbols.js
    terminal-highlight.js
    tokenize.js
    warn-once.js
    warning.d.ts
    warning.js

